# Can't connect to local DB via Firebird alias without specifying network address

Tags: windows, firebird

Old software that I no longer have the code for was running fine on Windows 7 (x32, I think) and Firebird 2.5 until recently. User would specify database alias "med" and the software would connect.

A new PC with Windows 7 x64 and Firebird 2.5 was installed. Old software is running but when trying to connect to the database it fails with this error

```
ISC ERROR CODE:335544344

ISC ERROR MESSAGE:
I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file ":med"
Error while trying to open file
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

If I include host name i.e. "IP_ADDRESS:med" - it works, but this causes some separate problems in the program that I would like to avoid.

If I try from isql with just the alias - it works.

It is possible that the old code was trying to use the local protocol when the file is local (database name specified without network address). I don't know if it could be related to the problem.

I tried copying the firebird.conf from the old PC over the current one.

I am thankful for any ideas or suggestions.

edit: I did as MarkRotteveel suggested, added a ":med" alias to aliases.conf and it does connect now so that potentially solved everything but still leaves the confusion of what actually happened/what could be different from the original system...

Comment: how do you configure the conneciton string? ":med" is weird - there can be no colon in file names! it should be plain "med" without colons or other special symbols

Comment: Colon in that error message is weird, I agree. I just enter "med" in the web form.

Comment: If it was some new code I'd assume it had an error and tried to open the file with colon in the name, but the program is 5 years old and worked fine, unless if I have completely missed some piece of the story.

Comment: Without a [mre] it is hard to provide an answer. If you installed a 64-bit Firebird, try uninstalling it and installing a 32-bit Firebird instead (or vice versa). If all else fails, define an extra alias `:med` in `aliases.conf` of your Firebird install as a workaround. Also consider asking on the [firebird-support](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support) Google Group

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you, my man, are pure genius! Adding :med worked. I am still confused as heck about the whole thing and have to test various stuff but if that's the bandaid that makes it work then that's fine with me :)

Comment: i may blind guess you somehow managed to enter remote computer name as some space or other invisible simbol, or like an mpty string instead of no data at all, but since we do not know your program this guesswork would be for naught. You might want to compare program configuration data on both computers, or very carefully compare text in all setup windows, etc.

Comment: @Arioch'The it's all local to the application which is a web server accessing a database on same computer, in theory it could access a different host but it never did... idk I am still confused and will need to investigate tomorrow to see if its all good with the bandaid

Comment: @MarkRotteveel if you turn your comment into an answer I will accept it since it seems it fully solved my problems after today's testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an answer to your question, but at least a workaround for the problem: create an extra alias in `aliases.conf` of your Firebird instance with the `:` as a prefix (so, add `:med = <path-to-your-database>`). This will allow Firebird to connect.

As far as I'm aware, Firebird nor fbclient.dll will add the colon itself, so likely something in your program is doing that automatically when it detects the absence of a hostname.

Comment: I guess it is possible that it always was this way and that a different version of FB server/fb client dll/something else tolerated or ignored the colon. Thank you.

Comment: @Milos if you can run the old computer and it uses stand-alone server v.2.5, then you may try http://fbprofiler.sf.net and perhaps you would see which connection request was made. Dunno is aliases substitutions are made before or after TraceAPI, but trying is free